# karma + jasmine unit tests show define is not defined

Tags: unit-testing, gulp, karma-jasmine

I am using Karma and jasmine to write my unit tests.  I transpile ES6 code to ES5 to run the tests on but when ever I run the tests I get an error saying:

```
Chrome 51.0.2704 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

My **karma.conf.js** is this:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Jun 08 2016 07:12:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jspm','jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        {pattern: 'lib/**/*.min.js', included: false},
        {pattern: 'js/Test/Dashboard/Unit/src/*.js', included: true},
        {pattern: 'js/Test/Dashboard/Unit/src/**/*.js', included: true},
        {pattern: 'js/Test/*Spec.js', included: true},
        {pattern: 'js/Test/**/*Spec.js', included: true}
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['chrome_without_security'],

    customLaunchers: {
        chrome_without_security: {
            base: 'Chrome',
            flags: ['--disable-web-security']
        }
    },


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
})
}
```

The gulp task that runs the ES6-ES6 transpile is this:

```
gulp.task('build:aurelia', function(){
gulp.src([paths.dashboardPathJs, '!' + paths.dashboardJs])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(babel({ 
        presets: [ 'es2015-loose', 'stage-1'],
        plugins: [
            'syntax-flow',
            'transform-decorators-legacy',
            'transform-flow-strip-types',
            'transform-es2015-modules-amd'
        ] 
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/Test/Dashboard/Unit/src'));
});
```

I'm completely lost as to why I get the define is not defined error.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it is due to the testing library not getting loaded, so your test that has the define() in it, does not have the function declared? As you are using the transpile you might not have all the testing infrastructure loaded and transpiled into the executing JavaScript?

Comment: How do I proceed with loading the testing library properly?

Comment: In the test TypeScript file, I believe you need to include the files from your test library. I had issues with this a short time ago, and moved back to testing in JavaScript.  I did look to this site (https://www.xplatform.rocks/2016/02/01/testing-angular2-apps-with-jasmine-and-typescript/) among others.